# Setting codeigniter on server with folder url path

Tags: apache, codeigniter

I tried to put my codeigniter project into server, I want to achieve these schemas:
visit `http://156.67.214.100/sso` will visit /var/www/sso 
visit `http://156.67.214.100/purchasing` will visit /var/www/purchasing

my config for folder sso is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 156.67.214.100/sso

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sso/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/>
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
             Order allow,deny
             allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i try to visit `http://156.67.214.100/sso` will result page not found, because apache think the root is `http://156.67.214.100`, i want to the root is `http://156.67.214.100/sso`

Answer (score 0):

My start on my virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost 156.67.214.100/sso:80>
       ServerName 156.67.214.100/sso
       ServerAlias 156.67.214.100/sso
       DocumentRoot /var/www/sso/
```

I have a entry on /etc/hosts:

```
#(server ip)
192.168.0.10    156.67.214.100/sso
```

Each server is a strange world, just try to know!
Maybe it helps!